# Files getting corrupted every time

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-16.04, cuda

I am trying to download/copy a file. I tried from web and also from pendrive.  md5sum for the two files ( one in pendrive and one that I copied on desktop) are not matching at all. I copied using cp command also.  Also even web downloads are corrupted. however, I can perfectly download  in windows, but fail miserably in ubuntu 16.04. This happening for every file I am trying to copy.

What has happened?

**Edit**

Installing any .run file says that there is no enough space on /tmp and that the file may be corrupted.

```
sudo df -h
[sudo] password for hes: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            968M     0  968M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  3.8M  196M   2% /run
/dev/sda6       158G   19G  132G  13% /
tmpfs           997M   15M  982M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M   56K  200M   1% /run/user/1000
```

**The error:**

> :~/Desktop$ ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run  Extraction failed. Ensure
>   there is enough space in /tmp and that the installation package is not
>   corrupt Signal caught, cleaning up

[image]

I am still getting same two errors:

> :~$ ./cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux
>
> gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated Extraction
>   failed. Ensure there is enough space in /tmp and that the installation
>   package is not corrupt Signal caught, cleaning up

Comment: So where is `/tmp` located and how much free space is there? Have you tried cleaning up `/tmp`?

Comment: I am posting some update in a minute

Comment: @DavidPostill  I am getting same errors.  yes even after cleaning up

Comment: @DavidPostill as per the screenshot it shows 137 gb free space. Is that correct ?

Comment: So your downloads are corrupt.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, it is getting corrupted every time. Even if I try  copying it from usb drive to desktop it gets  damaged.

Comment: @DavidPostill The file in usb drive is not corrupted , and shows correct checksum, but when I copy it to desktop on ubuntu, it shows its checksum changed

Comment: @DavidPostill I have even tried installing using wget, but I always get checksum wrong

Comment: Does this problem occur with all downloads or only this specific file? What happens when you download the file from Windows, is it usable? Have you checked for filesystem/storage device/RAM errors? How are you connected to the local network? How are you connected to the Internet?

Comment: Are you copying by FTP or through a browser? If FTP, have you set binary mode? https://www.jscape.com/blog/ftp-binary-and-ascii-transfer-types-and-the-case-of-corrupt-files